# Java MVC model notify event to view

Tags: java, model-view-controller, gtk, agents-jade

I'm trying to notify event to my view when my model change.
My model already extends another class (Agent from JADE platform) so I can't use Observale. I don't want to do true MVC, just want to trigger an event from my model and change my view. Only one view, model, controller in my case.

Model

```
public class AgentSeeker extends Agent {
    private List<Music> musicsPurchased = new ArrayList<Music>();
    private List<ScoredMusic> musicsToBuy = new ArrayList<ScoredMusic>();

    public void buyMusic(ScoredMusic sm) {
        Music music = sm.getMusic();
        musicsPurchased.add(music);
        musicsToBuy.remove(sm);
    }
}
```

View

```
public class AgentSeekerView extends AbstractAgentView {
    TextView textViewMusicPurchased;

    public AgentSeekerView() {
        super("AgentSeeker.glade");
    }

    protected void initComposant() {
        super.initComposant();
        textViewMusicPurchased = (TextView) builder.getObject("music_purchased");
    }

    public void addMusicPurchasedToConsole(String music) {
        TextBuffer textBuffer = textViewMusicPurchased.getBuffer();
        textBuffer.insert(textBuffer.getIterEnd(), music + '\n');
    }

}
```

My controller

```
public class SeekerController {
    private final AgentSeeker model;
    private final AgentSeekerView view;

    public SeekerController(AgentSeeker model, AgentSeekerView view) {
        this.model = model;
        this.view = view;
    }
}
```

When I add music to my musicsPurchased list, I want to add this music to my TextBuffer from the view too.

Comment: What is calling `AgentSeeker.buyMusic()`? And are your model and view both GObjects?

Comment: It's an agent from JADE with an OneShotBehaviour who call buyMusic(). To be simple it's the model itself. My view use a TextView (GObject) and my model an ArrayList (Object). There is no link between those two for the moment. You can see the full implementation code here https://github.com/melkir/MusicTrading